# Cronjob executing multiple times at once

Tags: debian, python, cron

I have a cronjob similar to this:

*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/root/test.py >> /home/root/spring.1

In test.py, I am just printing the current time. After few mins of observation, I see this in spring.1 log file:

---

17/12/2009 10:09:01 AM

---

17/12/2009 10:09:01 AM

---

17/12/2009 10:09:01 AM

---

17/12/2009 10:09:01 AM

---

17/12/2009 10:09:01 AM

---

17/12/2009 10:10:01 AM

---

17/12/2009 10:10:01 AM

---

17/12/2009 10:10:01 AM

---

17/12/2009 10:10:01 AM

Anyone know what the problem may be? The python script is simply outputting the current time so we can say for sure that its cronjob which is opening the python multiple times.

Thanks.

Comment: This really belongs on Serverfault, and will probably be moved soon. In the meantime, have you checked if you have multiple cron daemons running?

Comment: I'm wondering why you'd use */1? Are you actually trying to say 01 * * * *? I'm actually curious, as I've not seen that notation before unless using some other divisor like /2 or /5....

Answer (score 1):

There was such a question here: the problem was in several cron instances running at once :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `crontab -l`? It might seem obvious but you might have the same script added several times. That's all I can think of.

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+1

Comment: yes, checked that. it only shows up once like it should.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys. rebooting the box fixed it. still not sure what the problem was but i think it may be that due to the number of edits i'd done to the cron configs, there were multiple instances of cron running.